# Pandas isin anywhere in a sentence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a standard pandas DataFrame consisting of string sentences (shown below) and I want to show the rows that have the word "world" anywhere in the 'body' of it.  `df.isin(['world'])` won't work because that only matches exact labels.  I want to return `True` if the word "world" shows up anywhere within the text of the 'body'.

```
  body
0 'Hello world hi hi'
1 'My name is David, hello'
2 ...
```

**The code that I tried was:**

```
df.isin(['world'])
```

which produces:

```
  body
0 False
1 False
2 ...
```

**What I'd like it to produce would be:**

```
  body
0 True
1 False
2 ...
```

because row `0` has the word "world" in it.

Comment: @SakibAhammed: I don't understand your question

Comment: I want to know, can you try this by implement? so need your implementation. And if you getting some wrong, then we will try to be correct

Comment: @David show your code

Comment: @SakibAhammed: added code. Very basic.

Comment: @David Yeah man, I know that. But It's stack overflow rules. Don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) as illustrated below.

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'body': ['Hello world hi hi', 'My name is David, hello']})

df['body'].str.contains('world')

# Result
0     True
1    False
```

Comment: Perfect, this did it. Thanks

Comment: This works nicely. The `isin` method in the original post wasn't returning wrong results. You just misunderstood the test being applied. If you had done `df['body'].isin(['Hello world hi hi'])` it would have indicated the first item a `True` match. `isin` is an "is the contents of a cell in this list?" test, not a "are any of the things in this list in each cell?" test.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `str.contains` Like:

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'body': ['Hello world hi hi', 'My name is David, hello']})

df['body'].str.contains('world')
```

Also if you want many string search, you can do it by:

```
mylist = ['Hello', 'world']    
In [11]: pattern = '|'.join(mylist)

In [12]: pattern
Out[12]: 'Hello|world'

In [13]: df['body'].str.contains(pattern)
Out[13]:
0     True
1    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a great addition.

Comment: @David Welcome. If you like this, you can accept this answer